# Insert a carriage return every 64 characters of a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a Base64 encoded string like this :

```
SWwgw6l0YWl0IHVuIHBldGl0IG5hdmlyZS [...] 0IG5hdmlyZSA=
```

The input String can big large (> 1MB). And for interoperability reasons, I need to add a carriage return into that large string every 64 characters.

The first guess I had was to use a stringbuilder and use the method "AppendLine" every 64 characters like this :

```
string InputB64_Without_CRLF = "SWwgw6l0YWl0IHVuIHBldGl0IG5hdmlyZS [...] 0IG5hdmlyZSA=";
int BufferSize = 64;
int Index = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (Index < strInput.Length) {
    sb.AppendLine(InputB64_Without_CRLF.Substring(Index, BufferSize));
    Index += BufferSize;
}

string Output_With_CRLF = sb.ToString();
```

But I'm worried about the performance of that portion of code. Is there a better means to insert a character into a string at a certain position without rebuilding another string ?

Comment: if you are using `Convert.ToBase64String`, you can use `Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks` parameter

Comment: That seems like a reasonable approach to me. Have you measured a performance problem?

Comment: I was mainly concerned about the duplication of my 1MB data stream from one string to another. But as a .NET string is immutable, we can't avoid that.

Comment: `Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks` unfortunately inserts the line breaks every 76 chars instead of 64. It's not configurable further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is there a better means to insert a character into a string at a certain position without rebuilding another string?*

.NET strings are immutable, which means that they cannot be modified once they have been created.

Therefore, if you want to insert characters into a string, there is no other way *but* to create a new one. And `StringBuilder` is quite probably the most efficient way to go about this, because it allows you to perform as many string-building steps as needed, and only create one single new string in the end.

Unless you've actually noticed performance problems in a real-world scenario, keep your current solution. It looks fine to me, at least from a performance point of view.

**Some further fine points to consider:**

If you're still not happy with your solution, I can think of only a few minor things that might make your current solution more efficient:

- Declare the `StringBuilder`s required capacity up-front, so that its backing character buffer won't have to be resized:

  ```
  var additionalCharactersCount = Environment.NewLine.Length * (input.Length / 64); 
  var sb = new StringBuilder(capacity: input.Length + additionalCharactersCount);
  ```
- Insert the complete input string into the `StringBuilder` first, then repeatedly `.Insert(…, Environment.NewLine)` every 64 characters.

  I am not at all certain whether this would actually improve execution speed, but it *would* get rid of the repeated string creation caused by `.Substring`. Measure for yourself whether it's faster than your solution or not.

Comment: Lol, we had the same thought, i changed my post to show just that a couple min ago. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not inefficient, trying to save 100ms or less is usually not worth the effort. But if you are concerned, here is another slightly more efficient way to insert a new line(which is sometimes\r\n, not just\n) every 64 characters

```
        string Output_With_CRLF = InputB64_Without_CRLF;
        //Start at last index so that our new line inserts do not move the text, making sure to input every 64th of the original string
        //This looks stupid to divide and multiply again, but it works because it is integer division
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(InputB64_Without_CRLF);
        for (int i = (InputB64_Without_CRLF.Length / 64) * 64; i >= 64; i -= 64)
            sb.Insert(i, Environment.NewLine);
```

This will only be a tiny bit more efficient than your original code, you likely won't notice much difference.

After talking with stakx i had this idea. By using the StringBuilder you do not create many strings over and over. The StringBuilder is very efficient and will handle its insert without creating more objects.

Comment: Why should this be more efficient? Strings are immutable and the insert will build a new 1Mb + 1 byte string for each inserted newline. I would say what he is doing (using StringBuilder) is better than what you propose.

Comment: @ds27680 i changed my solution. The previous one was only a very tiny bit more efficient because it did not create the additional StringBuilder object and insert is faster than sub string in my experience.